# Implementing Applicative#product

Tags: scala

Working on `Applicative#product` in [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), here's my `map2` code

```
 def product[G[_]](G: Applicative[G]):
        Applicative[({type f[x] = (F[x], G[x])})#f] = {
    val self = this

[omitted 'unit' and 'apply' function definitions]

       override def map2[A,B,C](fa: (F[A], G[A]), fb: (F[B], G[B]))
                              (f: (A,B) => C): (F[C], G[C]) = {

        val x: (F[A], F[B]) = (fa._1, fb._1)
        val y: (G[A], G[B]) = (fa._2, fb._2)
        val f: F[C] = map(x)(f.tupled)
        val g: G[C] = map(y)(f.tupled)
        (f, g)
      }
    }
  }
```

However, I don't know why the `map` argument expects a type of `(F[?], G[?])`. Why is this?

```
[error] C:\Users\Kevin\...\Applicative.scala:66: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (F[A], F[B])
[error]  required: (F[?], G[?])
[error]         val f: F[C] = map(x)(f.tupled)
[error]                           ^
[error] C:\Users\Kevin\...\Applicative.scala:67: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (G[A], G[B])
[error]  required: (F[?], G[?])
[error]         val g: G[C] = map(y)(f.tupled)
[error]                           ^
[error] two errors found
```

Comment: Note that you have the same name `f` of parameter `f: (A,B) => C)` and variable `val f: F[C] = `.

Comment: After re-naming `f` (good catch), I'm getting the same 2 compile-time errors.

Comment: What is the signature of `map`?

Comment: `def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]` (note code written by authors of FP in Scala)

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it's something like `def map[A, B](x: (F[A], G[A]))(f: ???): ???`.

Comment: Any way `x` is `(F[A], F[B])`, but it should be `F[(A, B)]` to use int `def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]`.

Comment: Ah. So my answer is wrong since it requires writing a new `map` function? I say "wrong" since overloading should be avoided if possible

Comment: You could try to convert `(F[A], F[B])` to `F[(A, B)]`.

Comment: Thanks. Why not create an answer for credit? I'll accept it once I implement it on my own (to avoid just reading your answer for learning purposes)

Comment: I don't think this answer will be useful for other users.

Comment: why's that? Is it because of my question being un-useful?

Comment: It's because your question is about coursera homework.

Comment: Oh, well I'm working on it since it's in FP in Scala, not coursera